# Bootstrap Navbar Brand not rendering in Navbar in Meteor Application

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, navbar

Trying to get a copy-paste of a simple Bootstrap navbar example to work in a Meteor application.

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            {{> navbar}}
        </header>
    </div>
</body>

<template name="navbar">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</template>
```

The navbar renders with the 3 page links as you would expect.  The "Brand" renders as a simple html link that sits above the navbar on the left side.

Just updated to Meteor 1.0.45

Installed Packages:

- accounts-google    1.0.4
- accounts-password  1.1.0
- accounts-ui  1.1.5
- alanning:roles     1.2.13
- autopublish        1.0.3
- bootstrap          1.0.1
- insecure           1.0.3
- jquery             1.11.3_2
- meteor-platform    1.2.2
- pascoual:pdfjs     1.0.68

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you are missing the `navbar-default` class on the `<nav>`

It should look like this.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
```

Also Try using the Mizzao Bootstrap Package.

```
meteor remove bootstrap 1.0.1
meteor add mizzao:bootstrap-3
```

Comment: Adding navbar-default has no effect.  Adding other classes, like navbar-inverse, have the expected effects on the part of the navbar that is rendering.  But, switching out the built-in bootstrap package for the mizzao bootstrap package does seem to have solved the problem!  Replacing mizzao:bootstrap-3 with twbs:bootstrap also works correctly.